# How to increase contrast of an image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans

I'm new to image processing and I want to know how to increase image brightness, contrast and saturation in JAVA.

Any example codes or API that can be used in NETBEANS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javafx.scene.effect there is a ColorAjust class that contains methods you need.
Check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html

Comment: I recommend you try to stay away from link-only answers. I would elaborate a little more on why the material inside this link answers their question.

Comment: Sometimes it seems to be the most straight forward way to me :P but thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @alexis sometimes it is straight forward. Your answer is certainly more than just copy and pasting the link but I would hate to see this flagged as a low quality answer when it was actually helpful, so I just wanted to give some advice. :)

Comment: @McAdam331 You are right! Will pay more attention in the future. I'm new to forums like this and still got a lot to learn. Thank you! ;)